# How to show all employees absent dates only in MS Access 2010 query?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I want to have a query which shows me records of only those employees that were absent on various dates.

I have two queries in MS Access 2010. One is **qAllDatesAllEmp** which has all monthly dates for all employees. Second is **qDailyWorkEmp** which shows date-wise the working of employees. Now, say Emp1 had only one missing date of `5-Jan-2019`; emp2 had `15-Jan-2019` missing and so on, the result should show me only these missing dates with employee names. What i have tried so far is that I have joined the date field from **qAllDatesAllEmp** to the date field in **qDailyWorkEmp** with join arrow pointing from **qAllDatesAllEmp** to **qDailyWorkEmp**. I also added the date field from **qDailyWorkEmp** to the query grid below but removed the check mark. When I run this query, it gives blank result. I would really welcome the experts' help on how to get the desired output below.

My Sample Data:

```
Query1: qAllDatesAllEmp contains {WorkDate; empID; empName; CityBased}
Query2: qDailyWorkEmp   contains {DailyDate; empID; empName; CityBased}
```

The SQL for this is as follows:

```
SELECT qDailyWorkEmp.empID, qDailyWorkEmp.empName, qDailyWorkEmp.CityBased
FROM qAllDatesAllEmp LEFT JOIN
     qDailyWorkEmp
     ON qAllDatesAllEmp.WorkDate = qDailyWorkEmp.DailyDate
WHERE (((qDailyWorkEmp.DailyDate) Is Null));
```

My desired output:

```
    empID; EmpName; MissingDate

    001;    ABC;       5-Jan-2019

    007;    LMN;      15-Jan-2019 

...and so on
```

Comment: Add sample data and if possible make it more about sql and less about Access user interface actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather from your question, it seems like you are on the right track with your `left join` query, however, since your `qAllDatesAllEmp` query contains the master data, you should output the data from this query for records for which the corresponding values are null in your `qDailyWorkEmp` query.

---

You also appear to have a typo in your query on this line:

```sql
qAllDatesAllEmp.WhatDate = qDailyWorkEmp.DailyDate
```

As you have stated in your question that the query `qAllDatesAllEmp` contains the fields:

```
Query1: qAllDatesAllEmp contains {WorkDate; empID; empName; CityBased}
```

`WhatDate` is not one of these fields.

---

You will also need to join the `empID` field in both queries, so that you are comparing the date field on a **per-employee** basis, as opposed to comparing each date with the dates for **all** employees - hence your join criteria should be:

```sql
qAllDatesAllEmp LEFT JOIN qDailyWorkEmp ON 
qAllDatesAllEmp.WorkDate = qDailyWorkEmp.DailyDate AND
qAllDatesAllEmp.empID = qDailyWorkEmp.empID
```

---

With the information provided, I might suggest the following:

```sql
SELECT 
    qAllDatesAllEmp.empID, 
    qAllDatesAllEmp.empName, 
    qAllDatesAllEmp.CityBased
    qAllDatesAllEmp.WorkDate as MissingDate
FROM 
    qAllDatesAllEmp LEFT JOIN qDailyWorkEmp ON 
    qAllDatesAllEmp.WorkDate = qDailyWorkEmp.DailyDate AND
    qAllDatesAllEmp.empID = qDailyWorkEmp.empID
WHERE 
    qDailyWorkEmp.DailyDate IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much Lee Mac. your solution worked for me. sorry for late response. But thank you again.